# I am unable to take the definite integral of an expression. My output is never a number, it is always an expression

Tags: python-3.x, sympy

This is my expression:

```
x = symbols('x')

expr=(8.21067284717243e+22*((1/(16.3934426229508*x - 0.19672131147541))**1.2)**0.5*(1/(16.3934426229508*x - 0.19672131147541))**0.6*log(1531.16571479152*(1/(16.3934426229508*x - 0.19672131147541))**1.2)**0.5)


integrate(expr, (x, 0, 5))
```

I am trying to integrate my mass loss expression (g/Gyr) to find the total mass loss over 5 Gyr.

Comment: What exactly is your question? Please describe it in more detail.

Comment: after moving `x = symbols('x')` before your expression and renaming to `integrate(expr, (x,0,5))` it works. Although it is hard to tell from your question and posted code what exactly the problem was.

Comment: I got `2.22352913318891e+23*Integral((0.136355245011469*log((1/(16.3934426229508*x - 0.19672131147541))**1.2) + 1.0)**0.5*((1/(16.3934426229508*x - 0.19672131147541))**1.2)**0.5*(1/(16.3934426229508*x - 0.19672131147541))**0.6, (x, 0, 5))`

Comment: @BijayRegmi Yes, okay I got this too. But, how do I get a numerical value?

Comment: You are getting back a function of `x`, if you want to get raw value, you need to define a value to x, that is a number. `function = integrate(expr, (x, 0, 5)) ` would store the integrated function of `x`  as `function`, now if i want to get raw value for `x=4`, I do something like `print(function.evalf(subs={x : 4})`

Comment: @BijayRegmi okay, I guess I was just under the impression that integrate(expr, (x, 0, 5)) would integrate my expr with respect to x with limits 0 and 5, which in turn would give me a numerical value of the integral

Comment: defining boundaries in integral stores these values in `function` too, if you want to directly get the values, use `print(integrate(expr, (x,0,5))).evalf()`

Comment: In your case the value would be `0.e+24 + 0.e+23*I`

Comment: @BijayRegmi sorry, I'm not that pro at python. I keep getting an AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'evalf'

Comment: make sure you are copying the exact code.